# Why each font in customFonts tag is a mutable array?

Tags: xml, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

For a long time I was curios about the XML behind the any storyboard file. And I try to understand each part of it.

This time I would like to know about this:

```
<customFonts key="customFonts">
    <mutableArray key="FontName-Bold.otf">
        <string>FontName-Bold</string>
    </mutableArray>
    <mutableArray key="FontName.otf">
        <string>FontName</string>
        <string>FontName</string>
        <string>FontName</string>
        <string>FontName</string>
        <string>FontName</string>
        <string>FontName</string>
        <string>FontName</string>
    </mutableArray>
</customFonts>
```

Why it is a mutable array? Why there are a lot of occurrences for the second font, but only one for the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one occurrence of `<string>FontName</string>` for each control in your storyboard which uses the font `"FontName.otf"`. Do you only have one control with `"FontName-Bold.otf"` but 7 that use the regular font?